# Collatz Conjecture Meet of 2 Numbers

Tags: java, algorithm, collatz-sequence

I need the most efficient way to calculate when the Collatz Conjecture of two numbers, `a` and `b` respectively, are the same. Here is my algorithm, which is too slow:

```
while(true) {
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        int b = sc.nextInt();

        if(a == 0 && b == 0) {
            break;
        }

        TreeMap<Integer, Integer> visited = new TreeMap<>();
        visited.put(a, 0);

        int A = a;
        int Acount = 0;

        while(A != 1) {
            Acount++;

            if(A % 2 == 0) {
                A /= 2;
            } else {
                A = A * 3 + 1;
            }

            if(!visited.containsKey(A)) {
                visited.put(A, Acount);
            }
        }

        int B = b;
        int Bcount = 0;

        while(B != 1) {
            if(visited.containsKey(B)) {
                out.println(a + " needs " + visited.get(B) + " steps, " + b + " needs " + Bcount + " steps, they meet at " + B);
                break;
            }

            if(B % 2 == 0) {
                B /= 2;
            } else {
                B = B * 3 + 1;
            }

            Bcount++;
        }

    }
```

After looking around on Github, I found [this](https://github.com/JonSteinn/Kattis-Solutions/blob/master/src/Collatz%20Conjecture/Python%203/collatz.py), and it worked, although it's essentially the exact same thing.

[Original problem](https://open.kattis.com/problems/collatz)

How do I fix my Java code to make it more efficient? I tried it literally at least four times.

Comment: Please do not edit "solutions" into your questions. That would be good form on 90's forums, but here it only results in confusion. Thanks!

Comment: (The alternatives to *editing "solutions" into one's question* include *answering* and posting another (cross-linked) question.)

Comment: I see. Won't do that from now on :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Integer Overflow

I suspect that your problem has to do with integer overflow and not with your algorithm itself.  If you don't guard against integer overflow, doing `A = A * 3 + 1` could result in a negative value, and you may end up in an infinite loop where you never reach 1.  Try changing your variables to `long` and resubmit.

By the way, to test for infinite loop cases, try the starting value 113383.

#### Other suggestions

- You could use a `HashMap` instead of a `TreeMap`.  A `HashMap` has \$O(1)\$ insert and lookup compared to \$O(\log n)\$ for a `TreeMap`.  The difference for this program will be very small though.
- In the `A` loop, you shouldn't have to check if `visited.containsKey(A)` because the collatz sequence never repeats until you reach 1.  You can just always add `A` to the map.
- If `b` is 1, your program never prints anything.

Comment: Problem is TLE not WA. I tried a TreeMap still in vain :(. I have to do visited.containsKey(A) because visited maps the first occurrence of A, if I overwrite that value, I lose the index i which associates with number A such that it is at a minimum. It is essential to not overwrite it for the output (per problem statement).

Comment: @ImagineDragons If you overflow you can get into an infinite loop, hence TLE. Did you even try it?  As far as overwriting the first occurrence, the collatz sequence has no cycles except at 1 so you should never get a second occurrence except at 1.

Comment: Trying right now, hopefully it works :). How can you prove it has no cycles where 1 < N <= 1 000 000 ?

Comment: Hmm now I am getting WA for some reason, but it seems correct...

Comment: @ImagineDragons See my latest edit.  Your program doesn't work if `b` is 1.  Also, did you remember to change your map to use `Long` instead of `Integer`?

Comment: Just fixed the algorithm too. Got submitted, finally! I thought I was going crazy over the Runtime Error. Thanks for your help it means a lot!

Comment: Also, how did you know there are no cycles in the Collatz Conjecture where 1 <= N <= 1 000 000? 

And the reason this problem occurred was due to integer overflow which resulted in values of A being negative (I guess).

Comment: @ImagineDragons If there were a cycle other than at 1, your program would infinite loop because it would just keep repeating the cycle in the A loop.  You can [read here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) where it says that no cycle has ever been found.

Comment: 113383 why this number, which i suspect is a prime..? Can you explain?

Comment: @Gewure If you start with this number, you will reach a number greater than \$2^{31}\$ and cause an overflow.  I found this starting number by running an incorrect program and detecting the first starting number that caused an infinite loop.